# How can I export a Linear Classifier to TFLITE format?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a Linear Classifier based on this example that works for exporting a DNN Classifier:

```
print("\n====== classifier model_dir, latest_checkpoint ===========")
print(classifier.model_dir)
print(classifier.latest_checkpoint())
debug = False

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # First let's load meta graph and restore weights
    latest_checkpoint_path = classifier.latest_checkpoint()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(latest_checkpoint_path + '.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint_path)
# Get the input and output tensors needed for toco.
# These were determined based on the debugging info printed / saved below.
input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/concat:0")
input_tensor.set_shape([1, 10])
out_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0")
out_tensor.set_shape([1, 5])

# Pass the output node name we are interested in.
# Based on the debugging info printed / saved below, pulled out the
# name of the node for the logits (before the softmax is applied).
frozen_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess, sess.graph_def, output_node_names=["dnn/logits/BiasAdd"])

if debug is True:
    print("\nORIGINAL GRAPH DEF Ops ===========================================")
    ops = sess.graph.get_operations()
    for op in ops:
        if "BiasAdd" in op.name or "input_layer" in op.name:
            print([op.name, op.values()])
    # save original graphdef to text file
    with open("estimator_graph.pbtxt", "w") as fp:
        fp.write(str(sess.graph_def))

    print("\nFROZEN GRAPH DEF Nodes ===========================================")
    for node in frozen_graph_def.node:
        print(node.name)
    # save frozen graph def to text file
    with open("estimator_frozen_graph.pbtxt", "w") as fp:
        fp.write(str(frozen_graph_def))

tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(frozen_graph_def, [input_tensor], [out_tensor])
open("estimator_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

but I don't know which tensor to use in this section:

```
input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/concat:0")
    input_tensor.set_shape([1, 10])
    out_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0")
    out_tensor.set_shape([1, 3])
```

I have tried as input tensor: 
linear/linear_model/linear_model/weighted_sum:0 
shape: 1,5 
(because I couldn't find a tensor that works with 1,10)

and as output tensor with: linear/head/predictions/probabilities:0
shape 1,5

but when I tried to use it in android device the shape of the output tensor is no longer 1,5 but 1,10
And I don't know how to interpret this result, maybe the problem is that I Don't know which tensor to choose as input to the toco_convert function

Comment: When using an estimator or linearclassifier I recommend you export to a SavedModel. The SavedModel contains information about inputs and outputs needed by toco_convert. And toco_convert supports converting directly from SavedModel which can avoid you needing to figure out inputs and outputs :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have an example of the use of the function to make a tflite file using a saved model (following a video of a tensorflow convention), I have tried to used that but I haven't find that function.
And how do you get this saved model, which function are you using? can you provide a little example of this 2 parts of the code. Thank you

Comment: Now  I know with function to used but still don't find the correct parameters, how did you saved the model using a premade estimator?

Comment: For the conversion from SavedModel to TFLite FlatBuffer, use TocoConverter.from_saved_model as documented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md#basic-savedmodel). As for how to generate a SavedModel, [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#build_and_load_a_savedmodel) documentation may be a good starting point. It would be helpful if you provided an updated code sample that shows how you are generating your model.